# Oracle 11.2 restore DB to a specific point

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman, datapump, flashback

I should execute following tasks:
1. test system and during test change Oracle data and Create New/Remove Old datafiles and tablespace.
2. at the end of test rollback to behviour before of point 1.

I'm working on Oracle 11.2 on two different sites: on single instance configuration and another in DataGuard environment.

To reach the scope I think following possibilities:
1) a- execute dump before starting.
   b- recreate manually datafiles/tablespaces and import data from dump at the end.

2) a- backup via RMAN all the DB.
   b- restore via RMAN the backup at the end.

3) a- create recovery-point.
   b- flashback at the end ....???? (I'm not sure about this chance with change on Datafiles and tablespace.

What your opinion on it?
Thanks,
 Ste

Comment: How much data is going to change? This is the most important thing, as it affects the decision to use flashback

Comment: Not a huge volume of data, about 500MB/1GB

Comment: Could be possible to use an image copy to switch with "SWITCH DATABASE TO COPY" and back the DB again at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very first lines in the Oracle Documentation about Flashback Database feature ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta023.htm#RCMRF194 ):

> *This command works by undoing changes made by Oracle Database to the data files that exist when you run the command.*

Flashback its mean to undo logical changes in the database. A Backup its a cloned copy of your database in a point in time. So, if you want to reproduce the exactly same environment for any subsequent tests, involving DB changes, you should go for a RMAN backup/restore technique.

Also, for the single instance DB, If it's going to be just a Test environment, you could avoid the creation of Archives and Flashback logs for saving lots of space, and create/restore from cold backups.

Scripting to recreate the DB + dp exp/imp can be another option, but its a waste of time having RMAN.